# Loop Through Generated Characters

Tags: java, loops

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int length=0;
    int MaxNumber=100;
    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();





    do {
        if (PasswordGenerator.matchLength (length)) {
            break;
        }
        length++; // length is randomly picked
    } while (length < MaxNumber );   // or <100
    System.out.println("The length of the character string is " + length);


    int index = 0;
    char f = 0;


    for (char d = 0; d < 127; d++) {
        if(PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt(d, index)) {
            password.append(d);
            System.out.println("Hey! Char at " + index + " is " + d);
            d++;
        }
    }



}
}
```

So I have found how to find the first character of my randomly generated password via loop, and was wondering how I could provide it to find the other characters in the password by using either that loop or another.  The characters follow how long the loop is which is also randomly generated.  The documentation to the PasswordGenerator class is here.. (http://www.technology.heartland.edu/faculty/todds/csci130/assignments/A5_password/doc/index.html)

Comment: That `PasswordGenerator` thing is pretty poor, it should be able to at least give you the length of the password without forcing you to loop over the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of `index` to the position of the character you are trying to find. If you want to find all of them then...

```
for(int j=0; j < length; j++)
{
      for (char d = 0; d < 127; d++) 
      {
        if(PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt(d, j)) 
        {
            password.append(d);
            System.out.println("Hey! Char at " + index + " is " + d);

            // No sense in incrementing d and going through all of them
            // You found it already, break this loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are appending the characters to the password `StringBuilder`. When it finishes the `password` variable will have the whole thing. You can then print that. If you want newlines between every single character in `password` use `.appendLine()`. Please read the API before asking questions.